# Django checkbox for filter

Tags: django, django-templates

Im having some problem when I want to keep a checkbox checked. When I send the form all the checkbox are checked. so idk how to change the if statement for that :(

```
 <div class="form-group">
                <label >Marca</label>
                {% for brand in q %}
                <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
                    <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="{{brand.brand}}" name="test" value="{{brand.brand}}" {% if marca %} checked="checked" {%endif%}>
                    <label class="custom-control-label" for="{{brand.brand}}" style="cursor: pointer;">{{brand.brand}}</label>
                    </div>
                {% endfor %}

            </div>
```

And here is the view:

```
marca = request.GET.get('test')
if marca :
    products = products.filter(brand__name__in=request.GET.getlist('test'))
```

All the other things are fine. It shows me the brands that I choose. So I just want to keep the checkbox that I checked :( and I think the problem is that If statement in the template

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just pass a set of the values in the values to the template:

```
marca_vals = set(request.GET.getlist('test'))
# …
context = {
    'marca_vals': marca_vals,
    # …
}
return render(request, 'some_template.html', context)
```

in the template you can then render it with `checked` in case the value is in the `marca_vals`:

```
<input type="checkbox" {% if brand.brand in marca_vals %}checked{% endif %} class="custom-control-input" id="{{brand.brand}}" name="test" value="{{brand.brand}}">
```

You might however want to consider using a form, or even [**`django-filters`** [readthedocs]](https://django-filter.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) to both make filtering and *rendering* the form more convenient.

Comment: I did it and it keeps being the same:( it doesn't keep the check

Comment: @AlexCuadra: you did pass `marca_vals` to the template? What happens if you render `{{ marca_vals }}`?

Comment: Yes, i pass it like you told me but nothing is checked after I submitted. And if I only render like {{marca_vals}} all the checkboxes are checked

Comment: @AlexCuadra: no, I simply means, what do you see in the template if you render `{{ marca_vals }}`. This is to check if the values are passed to the template correctly.

Comment: But in the checkboxes doesnt keep it :/ thats weird

Comment: @AlexCuadra: but you did remove the `{% if brand %}checked{% endif %}` at the end right?

Comment: Yeah, i left it the way you wrote it with {% if brand.brand in marca_vals %}checked{% endif %}

Comment: @AlexCuadra: there is nothing else that is `checked`ing the input? What is `brand.brand` exactly?

Comment: Brand is a foreign key that product has, so I call it like brand.brand so I can only grab their name